# Facebook manifest blocked by CORS policy

Tags: facebook

We cannot open Facebook web game due to the following error

Access to manifest at 'https://www.facebook.com/data/manifest/' (redirected from 'https://apps.facebook.com/data/manifest/') from origin 'https://apps.facebook.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is there anything abnormal on Facebook back end server?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/334419494785266/

Answer (score 0):

Though this a problem that facebook should solve

A workaround that worked for us is as follows

1. Go in to developers.facebook.com -> Settings -> Basic
2. Set WebGL to NO.

Comment: Actually, the WebGL is No. However, this error is still there...